# October CMS Relation field returns empty data

Tags: octobercms

I'm stuck with the relations.

1. I've created the both dbs

   Skill (int id, string title)
   Event (int id, string title, Text skills)
2. added the relation field into Event's fields.yaml file

   skills:
           label: Skills
           nameFrom: title
           descriptionFrom: description
           span: auto
           type: relation
3. the pivot table foo_bar_events_skills (int event_id, int skill_id)
4. Added the relations into both Model files

   ```
   Event Relation :
   public $belongsToMany =[
       'skills' => [
           'foo\bar\Models\Skill', 
           'table' => 'foo_bar_events_skills',
           'order' => 'title'
       ]   
   ];



   Skill Relation :
   public $belongsToMany =[
       'events' => [
           'foo\bar\Models\Event', 
           'table' => 'foo_bar_events_skills',
           'order' => 'title'
       ]   
   ];
   ```

So, now I can add skills to Events - I checked the pivot table and it had the proper values in it, but when I'm trying to display my skills data using foreach loop

```
{% for skill in event.skills %}
    {{skill}}
{% endfor %}
```

it returns nothing. And other 'event' entity's fields are fully accessible.

Please, share any ideas why would this happen, thanks in advance.

P.S. When I checked current event's values in the database, I noticed, that my 'skills' field is null. Is it ok, or I missed something?

UPD I tried to add

```
        'otherKey' => 'event_id', 
        'key' => 'skill_id'
```

to my belongsToMany description, so it looks like

```
public $belongsToMany =[
    'skills' => [
        'foo\bar\Models\Skill', 
        'table' => 'agm_foo_bar_skills',
        'order' => 'title',
        'key' => 'event_id', 
        'otherKey' => 'skill_id'
    ]   
];
```

But it also doesn't work

UPD2. Standard CMS tools didn't help, so I had to acquire data from the relation table manually.

Comment: you don't need to add `Text skills` field in `Events`, its not needed `relational data` will be stored in to the `foo_bar_events_skills` table so you `do not need that`, it `confuse Laravel` and you get `blank result of that field` rather then `your relation` so please remove that field.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Hardik!
I removed the "skills" column from table, but getting blank results still. May be I'm missing something more?

Comment: Ok did you remove from database as well, if so just now try to add new record of event and use that to show skills it should be there..

Comment: Nah, checked that this field doesn't exist both in CMS and pgAdmin - skills doesn't display still, even in newly created page :(

Comment: can you share how you show field in FROM, how you establish reaction in backend using form.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure i understand you quite right, could you rephrase your last message?

Comment: in backend you are adding data like title of event in form, there how you attach skill with that, are  you using `config_relation.yaml` to show relation in backend-form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182142/discussion-between-occams-chainsaw-and-hardik-satasiya).